# How to make a video change at specific times javascript

Tags: javascript, intervals

Hi guys i have a problem. 
I want a video link in a website to change its value each day randomly.

Example: On Monday video link 1 plays. On Tuesday link 2 plays and so on.
I want to do this with Javascript.
I tried something like this:

```
<iframe id="videorotator" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;" width="307" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/UZopKnDHti8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<script type="text/javascipt">
var videos = ["http//www.youtube.com/embed/UZopKnDHti8","http://www.youtube.com/embed/z8GHNhteHJQ"];
var i=0;

function myLoop () {           
    setTimeout(function () {   
        var yourElement = document.getElementById('videorotator');
        yourElement.setAttribute('src', "="+videos[i]);        
        i++;                
        if (i < 6) {         
            myLoop();         
        }                   
    }, 3000)
}

myLoop();
</script>
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4aearfvr/

NOTE1: i set this to 3seconds for the sake of testing
NOTE2: if there is an easier work around please inform me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display a video based on what day of the week it is, then I suggest you do it like this

```
var videos =["UZopKnDHti8","z8GHNhteHJQ","UZopKnDHti8","z8GHNhteHJQ","UZopKnDHti8","z8GHNhteHJQ","z8GHNhteHJQ"];
var day = new Date().getDay();

var yourElement = document.getElementById('videorotator');
yourElement.setAttribute( 'src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/' + videos[ day ] );
```

`getDay` returns 0 = sunday, 1 = monday, 2 = tuesday ... which is perfect for accessing an array

In the array I added just the id's, there's no need to repeat `http://www.youtube.com/embed/` 7 times, might as well just append the ID to the url when you use `setAttribute`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4aearfvr/5/)

In the demo you can see the thumbnail flick from the original video to the correct one, simply remove the original src and it'll work smoother

Answer (score 1):

*[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/4aearfvr/9/)*

```
var day = new Date().getDay();  
var video = document.getElementById('videorotator');
var videos =[
    "http//www.youtube.com/embed/UZopKnDHti8",
    "http://www.youtube.com/embed/z8GHNhteHJQ"
];

video.setAttribute('src', videos[day%videos.length]);
```

You said you want one video/day, so get the day number and get the video src.

Comment: Have you tested this? `yourElement` is not set anywhere in this snippet or on your jsfiddle demo