# How do I change the Background video by time of day and day of the week?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I need to make my background video change by time of the day and day of the week. for example day video during day, night video during night, and Monday and Tuesday etc etc have different videos for night and day. So there would be a total of 14 background videos. I don't know if PHP of JS or JQUERY would be better.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    
    day=new Date()     //..get the date
    
    x=day.getHours()    //..get the hour
    
    if(x>=0 && x<4) {
    
       document.write('<style type="text/css">body{background: white url(1st.jpg); color: black}"></style>')
    
    } else
    
    if(x>=4 && x<12) {
    
       document.write('<style type="text/css">body{background: white url(2nd.jpg); color: black}</style>')
    
    } else
    
    if(x>=12 && x<18) {
    
       document.write('<style type="text/css">body{background: white url(3rd.jpg); color: black}</style>')
    
    } else
    
    if (x>=18 && x<24) {
    
       document.write('<style type="text/css">body{background: white url(4th.jpg); color: black}</style>')
    
    }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: May helpful this ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077041/refresh-image-with-a-new-one-at-the-same-url

Comment: Also this may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908991/how-to-make-a-video-change-at-specific-times-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so I am not sure you are still looking for an answer, but I thought I would take a stab at it.

You could do this with any scripting language. Doing it on the server before sending the content to the client's browser might load faster, but you would have to consider users who are not in the same time zone as the server. That would mean somehow getting the client's timezone. There are several ways to do that. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905397/how-to-get-clients-timezone) for ideas on how to do that. Once you have the client's timezone, you could do it with PHP like this:

```
$client_timezone = 'America/New_York';
$today = new DateTime();
$today->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($client_timezone));
$hour = $today->format('H'); // 24-hour format
$weekday = $today->format('w'); // number from 0 - 6
$day_videos = array('sun1.mp4', 'mon1.mp4', 'tue1.mp4', 'wed1.mp4', 'thu1.mp4', 'fri1.mp4', 'sat1.mp4');
$night_videos = array('sun2.mp4', 'mon2.mp4', 'tue2.mp4', 'wed2.mp4', 'thu2.mp4', 'fri2.mp4', 'sat2.mp4');
$video = 'default.mp4';
if($hour >= 18 || $hour < 6) { // I arbitrarily chose 6 PM as night and 6 AM as day
    $video = $night_videos[$weekday];
} else {
    $video = $day_videos[$weekday];
}

echo $video;
```

You can find more info about the PHP DateTime object [here](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-oop/php-datetime/).

I don't like the user experience of getting the client time zone and then reloading or redirecting the page unless that is already happening via a form submission or something similar. If you are already getting information from the client someway before they get to the page where you are showing the video, then I would suggest server side because it makes the page load faster because the client isn't taking the time to figure out which video to load. If you are not already getting information from the client somehow before loading this page (like if it is the landing page of your site) then I would recommend using client side. Depending on the size of the videos you may want to display a "loading" element of some kind while the calculation is done and the page loads. Here is how you could do it in JavaScript:

```
const dayVideos = ['sun1.mp4', 'mon1.mp4', 'tue1.mp4', 'wed1.mp4', 'thu1.mp4', 'fri1.mp4', 'sat1.mp4'];
const nightVideos = ['sun2.mp4', 'mon2.mp4', 'tue2.mp4', 'wed2.mp4', 'thu2.mp4', 'fri2.mp4', 'sat2.mp4'];
const now = new Date();
const h = now.getHours();
const w = now.getDay();
let video = 'default.mp4';
if(h >= 18 || h < 6) video = nightVideos[w];
else video = dayVideos[w];

console.log(video);
```

You can find more info about the JavaScript Date object [at the W3Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).